# How does np.random.normal works?

Tags: python, numpy, normal-distribution

I was starting to learn `np.random.normal` and the example code given was like:

```
np.random.normal(0.75)
```

and this command was giving a number as output.
Then i ran the same example without any input within brackets:

```
np.random.normal()
```

and again it gave an output.

when I looked for the documentation it was:

```
numpy.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=None)
```

I understood that `loc` is mean and scale is standard deviation and documentation makes all sense.
But why example code giving an output even without definig mean and std dev and even without any input?

Comment: When you don’t pass arguments the defaults (0.0 &1.0) are used. As the docs say, if you don’t pass a size, a single value is returned.

Comment: so what is 0.75 in the first example?

Comment: 0.75 will be the mean of the distribution.

Answer (score 3):

The loc, scale, and size have default values of 0.0, 1.0, and None respectively. Thus if you do not enter values of your own the defaults will be used.